# PythonAnywhere WSGI Typeerror: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

Recently, I'm trying to make Dixit online server for school festival from https://github.com/arvoelke/Dixit, But I have encountered a problem. when I reload my web app on my own Pythonanywhere web tab, an error log says,

> 'Typeerror: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)'.

I tried to find where '**call**()' function is in every Dixit code, but I can't find it. What should I do?

Here's a code related to WSGI, this one is 'server.py'.

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
"""Main application class for holding all state."""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Initializes the users, games, chat log, and cards."""
    self.users = Users()
    self.games = []
    self.chat_log = ChatLog()

    # Specifies where to find all the card images for each set.
    self.card_sets = [CardSet(name, find_cards(folder), enabled)
        for name, (folder, enabled) in kwargs['card_sets'].iteritems()]
    self.admin_password = kwargs['admin_password']

    super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

settings = {
    'static_path' : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
    'template_path' : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
    'debug' : True
}

configFilename = (sys.argv + ['config.json'])[1]
settings.update(config.parse(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
configFilename)))

application = Application([
(r'/', MainHandler),
(r'/admin', AdminHandler),
(r'/main.js', MainJSHandler),
(r'/main.css', MainCSSHandler),
(r'/setusername', SetUsernameHandler),
(r'/create', CreateHandler),
(r'/getgames', GetGamesHandler),
(r'/getusers', GetUsersHandler),
(r'/game/([0-9]+)/(.+)', GameHandler),
(r'/chat', ChatHandler),
], **settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    application.listen(settings['port'])
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and this one is 'jangheunghsstudentserver_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py'.

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi

def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ.get('PATH_INFO') == '/':
        status = '200 OK'
        # content = HELLO_WORLD
    else:
        status = '404 NOT FOUND'
        content = 'Page not found.'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(content)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    yield content.encode('utf8')

import sys

path = '/home/JangheungHSStudentServer/DixitOnline'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
from server import application
```

note. I don't use any python web framework such as django, flask.

Comment: did it show any line no regarding that problem?

Comment: Sorry. i didn't understand what are you talking about(I mean, what is 'it'?
, because I'm a python beginner, sorry)
But if you're talking about this:
- Does that error message shows regardless of any code?
  = No. it only appears when i run file named ''jangheunghsstudentserver_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py'.

Comment: The 1st snippet seems to be part of *Dixit* so unless you modified it (I don't see a reason why doing that) it shouldn't be posted in the question. Second, I'm not familiar with this framework, which file is the entry point? Something that doesn't seem right to me is that in the 2nd file you have `def application` and `import application`. Isn't there any more info related to the exception?

Comment: can you provide the full traceback?